# Virtual Machine Manager Set Logical Network with VLAN tag

Tags: scvmm

I have been running Hyper-V and setting VLAN tags on my NICs, this has been working great to partition the guest traffic between VLANs on my switch/router, such as SERVERS, LAB-A, LAB-B and so forth (lab-a and lab-b being research and development networks).

Each Hyper-V server is connected to the switch with its 4 NICs in a team, VLAN tagging happens across all, and the server is managed on a management VLAN.

I am now using Virtual Machine Manager 2012 and would like to offer self provisioning, however I need to let users from research and development labs only create virtual machines that can be connected to those networks - I want to avoid users setting the VLAN tag from within the virtual machine properties.

I cant see how I can define VLAN tags on the fabric logic networks, is there any other way to achieve the above?